# Cannot retrieve correct historic rates using Coinbase Pro API

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm trying to retrieve historical data for coinbase products. According to [their documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-historic-rates), it should be sufficient to perform a request like this one:

```
curl "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BCH-EUR/candles?granularity=60&start=2018-10-05T14:00:00.000z&stop=2018-10-05T14:10:00.000z"
```

I've set following parameters:

- `granularity` to 60 (seconds)
- `start` to `2018-10-05T14:00:00.000z` (iso 8601)
- `end` to   `2018-10-05T14:10:00.000z` (iso 8601)

I'm asking data for 10 minutes, with a granularity of 60 seconds, so I was expecting ten candles data.

Instead I obtain a set of 300 candles, that's the maximum, and the timestamps are also wrong. For example the first value is:

```
[
    [
        1624119060,
        484.31,
        484.31,
        484.31,
        484.31,
        0.11766122
    ],
    ...
]
```

The timestamp is the first value, and according to an [epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), it's equal to `Saturday, 19 June 2021 16:11:00`, that's the day in which I performed the request, not the timestamp that I was expenting for that candle data according to start date that I've set.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What should I do in order to retrieve data correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `end`, not `stop`. You quote the doc correctly, but the param itself is incorrect. Already voted to close this one as typo-based. :)

What's funny about their API is that if one of the params is omitted, another is just ignored. That's why you end up having incorrect timestamps in your response.

Comment: You're welcome, it happens. :) Actually I'm going to retract my vote; sooner or later someone ends up mixing those words too.